# How to receive caller number from Arduino SIM800C GSM shield?

Tags: arduino, gsm, atmega

I'm trying to code a GSM caller number receiver. When I (as the phone answerer) answer the phone it should print out the caller number.

I have trouble finding the right AT command for receiving the caller number. I tried `AT+CLIP=1\r` and on the loop `+CLIP`, but with no success.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <GSMSim.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define RX 7
#define TX 8
#define RESET 2
#define BAUD 9600

GSMSim gsm;
SoftwareSerial mySerial =  SoftwareSerial(RX, TX);
/*
 * Also you can this types:
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX);
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX, RESET);
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX, RESET, LED_PIN, LED_FLAG);
 */

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("GSMSim Library - Call Example");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  gsm.start(); // baud default 9600
  mySerial.read();
  mySerial.print("AT+CLIP=1\r");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(gsm.callStatus());
  gsm.callAnswer();
  Serial.println("Number:");
  Serial.println(mySerial.print("+CLIP"));
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: `Serial.println(mySerial.print("+CLIP"));` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: I just love it when someone posts a question and doesn't react to comments... If you're waiting for a ready-made solution, you're in for a long wait.

Comment: Hint: `size_t Print::print(const char str[])`. Guess what `print` returns?

Comment: @dda Sorry, I dident anwser sooner, but I got it working, problem was that I dident use mySerial.read( ) function

Answer (score 1):

I got It working by using mySerial, (ATDevice) read function and using command function to accualy print it out, anyone who looks up how it work, here Is my code

```
#include <GSMSim.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>



#define RX 7
#define TX 8
#define RESET 2
#define BAUD 9600

char outArray;
char inData[20]; 
char inChar=-1; 
byte index = 0; 
char * pch;
char* substring(char*, int, int);

GSMSim gsm;
  SoftwareSerial ATDevice =  SoftwareSerial(RX, TX);
/*
 * Also you can this types:
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX);
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX, RESET);
 * GSMSim gsm(RX, TX, RESET, LED_PIN, LED_FLAG);
 */

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);
  ATDevice.begin(9600);

  command("AT+CLIP=1",1000);
  delay(1000);


}


  String command(const char *toSend, unsigned long milliseconds) {
    String result;
    ATDevice.println(toSend);
    unsigned long startTime = millis();
    Serial.print("Return: ");
    while (millis() - startTime < milliseconds) {
      if (ATDevice.available()) {
        char c = ATDevice.read();
        result += c;  // append to the result string
      }
    }
  Serial.println();  // new line after timeout.
  return result;
  }


void loop() {

      command("+CLIP",1000);



     delay(2000);



}
```